# RavenDB Custom Serializer and Deserializer

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, ravendb, document-database

I'm having some trouble serializing/deserializing in RavenDB. I have no problems storing the data, but have an issue when querying the documents.

I have a fairly complex Account class that was generated from Entity Framework v4.3 POCO generator:

```
[Serializable]
public class Account
{
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
public List<Product> ProductsOwned { get; set; }
public bool IsActive { get; set; }
public Nullable<DateTime> DOB { get; set; }
public Address HomeAddress { get; set; }

// shortened for brevity
}
```

When I query my objects and return them as a List, I get a .NET Reflection Error "object does not match target type".

```
var results = (from account in mySession.Query<Account>()
               where account.IsActive == true
               select account).ToList<Account>(); // this is where error occurs
```

I thought this could be because I have other nested classes and nullables that are being serialized as well when I save it, but I found that I could create a "wrappper" class called AccountWrapper like this:

```
public class AccountWrapper
{
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public string SerializedText { get; set; }

}
```

Here I would manually use JSON.NET (yes, the same .dll's that shipped with RavenDB Buid 960) to populate the SerializedText field and then store it to RavenDB.  This process would work!  I would get the AccountWrapper object out of RavenDB and then manually deserialize the contents of SerializedText.   This leads me to believe there may be an issue with the default (de)serialization process.

So my question is, is there a way I can manually override the Serialize/Deserialize functionality on RavenDB when I store/load my documents?  If so, can someone show me a clean example of how to do so? I could then possibly make it use the standard `JsonConverter.Serialize()` as part of JSON.NET

Obviously using the AccountWrapper is a bad idea because I can't index on the "real" data that I need to query on.

(Full Stack Trace of Exception Below)

```
     System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract.InvokeOnDeserialized(Object o, StreamingContext context) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonContract.cs:line 172
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IWrappedCollection wrappedList, JsonReader reader, String reference, JsonArrayContract contract) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 774
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.<>c__DisplayClass1.<CreateAndPopulateList>b__0(IList l, Boolean isTemporaryListReference) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 744
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.CollectionUtils.CreateAndPopulateList(Type listType, Action`2 populateList) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Utilities\CollectionUtils.cs:line 233
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateAndPopulateList(JsonReader reader, String reference, JsonArrayContract contract) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 732
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String reference) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 495
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 238
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueProperty(JsonReader reader, JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, Object target, Boolean gottenCurrentValue, Object currentValue) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 213
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonReader reader, Object target) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 617
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, String id) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 1203
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateAndPopulateObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, String id) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 956
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 433
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 236
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueNonProperty(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonConverter converter) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 221
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 117
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:line 421
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:line 413
   at Raven.Client.Connection.JsonExtensions.Deserialize(RavenJObject self, Type type, DocumentConvention convention) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\JsonExtensions.cs:line 30
   at Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.ConvertToEntity[T](String id, RavenJObject documentFound, RavenJObject metadata) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.cs:line 416
   at Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.TrackEntity[T](String key, RavenJObject document, RavenJObject metadata) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.cs:line 340
   at Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation.Deserialize[T](RavenJObject result) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\SessionOperations\QueryOperation.cs:line 130
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation.Complete[T]() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\SessionOperations\QueryOperation.cs:line 114
   at Raven.Client.Document.AbstractDocumentQuery`2.GetEnumerator() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\AbstractDocumentQuery.cs:line 616
   at Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryInspector`1.GetEnumerator() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Linq\RavenQueryInspector.cs:line 98
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Comment: Could you show a stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: added stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 3):

This should work, can you provide additional details, and a failing test case would be great.

At any rate, you can customize this using:

```
documentStore.Conventions.CustomizeSerializer
```