# Querying RavenDB with a reflected type

Tags: c#, ravendb

I load types dynamically through reflection, instantiate the classes, fill them with data and then save them to RavenDB.  They all implement an interface `IEntity`.

In the RavenDB UI, I can see the classes correctly displayed and the meta data has the correct CLR type.

Now I want to get the data back out, change it and then save it.

### What I'd like to do

I have the `System.Type` that matches the entity in RavenDB's CLR meta data, assuming that's called `myType`, I would like to do this:

```
session.Query(myType).ToList(); // session is IDocumentSession
```

But you can't do that, as RavenDB queries like so:

```
session.Query<T>();
```

I don't have the generic type T at compile time, I'm loading that dynamically.

### Solution 1 - the Big Document

The first way I tried (for a proof of concept) was to wrap all the entities in a single data object and save that:

```
public class Data {
    List<IEntity> Entities = new List<IEntity>();
}
```

Assuming the session is opened/closed properly and that I have an id:

```
var myDataObject = session.Load<Data>(Id);

myDataObject.Entities.First(); // or whatever query
```

As my types are all dynamic, specified in a dynamically loaded DLL, I need my custom json deserializer to perform the object creation. I specify that in the [answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900283/how-do-i-use-a-custom-json-net-converter-in-ravendb-to-deserialize-into-types-fr)

I would rather not do this as loading the entire document in production would not be efficient.

<strike>## Possible solution 2 ##</strike>

I understand that Lucene can be used to query the type meta data and get the data out as a `dynamic` type. I can then do a horrible cast and make the changes.

---

### Update after @Tung-Chau

Thank you to Tung, unfortunately neither of the solutions work. Let me explain why:

I am storing the entities with:

```
session.Store(myDataObject);
```

In the database, that will produce a document with the name of `myDataObject.GetType().Name`. If you do:

```
var myDataObject = session.Load<IEntity>(Id);
```

Then it won't find the document because it is not saved with the name `IEntity`, it is saved with the name of the dynamic type.

Now the Lucene solution doesn't work either but for a slightly more complex reason. When Lucene finds the type (which it does), Raven passes it to the [custom JsonDeserialiser I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900283/how-do-i-use-a-custom-json-net-converter-in-ravendb-to-deserialize-into-types-fr). The custom Json Deserialiser does not have access to the meta data, so it does not know which type to reflect.

**Is there a better way to retrieve data when you know the type but not at compile time?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an ID (or IDs):

```
var myDataObject = session.Load<IEntity>(Id);
//change myDataObject. Use myDataObject.GetType() as you want 
//....
session.SaveChange();
```

For query, LuceneQuery is suitable

```
var tag = documentStore.Conventions.GetTypeTagName(typeof(YourDataType));
var myDataObjects = session.Advanced
                 .LuceneQuery<IEntity, RavenDocumentsByEntityName>()
                 .WhereEquals("Tag", tag)
                 .AndAlso()
                  //....
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Tung. Unfortunately, neither solution works. I've updated my post because the reasons are more complex than a comment will allow.